# Rails whenever not able to execute service methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service, cron, whenever

I have a NotificationService which has methods like this:

```
def trial teacher
    notification = Notification.create(recipient: teacher, tag: 'trial', text: 'text', title: 'title') 

    notification.deliver
end
```

I want to have a Whenever runner job to execute this method `... bin/rails runner "NotificationService.new.trial" --silent`, but if I try to do so I get an error `Please specify a valid ruby command or the path of a script to run.`. Yet if I try to use a model, not a service, it works (for instance, `Notification.last.deliver`)

And also that executes perfectly fine on development, but doesn't work on production. Seems like that service class doesn't exist for Cron

What am I missing?

Comment: I may be missing something but `NotificationService` is a class you defined yourself?

Comment: Can you run `NotificationService.new.trial` on rails console in production environment?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel yes, it's correct

Comment: @Tai yes, I can!

Comment: I can run all the methods of NotificationService on rails console on production environment. And I also figured out that I can run some of the methods through Cron, and others I can't and keep getting "Please specify a valid ruby command or the path of a script to run."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Turned out that the trouble was not with Whenever or Cron, but the exact method I was trying to run.
And as it was production environment with constantly changing data, when I ran NotificationService.new.trial I just got lucky not to get an error. Then data changed and Cron's attempts to run were failing.

Using safe navigation operator (&.) solved everything!